# How can I hardcode the Nextpage tag into a Wordpress theme file?

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I have a custom post type for a Slideshow which uses Custom Post Meta to insert the different slides.  How can I code the `<!--nextpage-->` tag in between the sides in my slideshow.php so that they slides will paginate?  Right now when I try to do it the code doesn't show because it by it's nature it commented out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the slides are each separate custom posts, the `<!--nextpage-->` tag won't work anyway.  `<!--nextpage-->` is designed to add pagination to long posts ... i.e. break a long, single post (or custom post type) over multiple pages.

From the sound of things, you want a pagination setup that will work for multiple individual custom posts.

What you want is the PHP function `next_post_link()`.  This "[template tag displays a link to the next post which exists in chronological order from the current post.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link)"

Comment: No, one post encompasses numerous slides.  I am not using the post content field to enter the content.  I am using custom meta boxes to enter custom post meta information for each slide.  I have template tags that insert each slide info into the slideshow.php file however  I need a way to specify a page break between each slide.

Comment: `<!--nextpage-->` wouldn't work in that situation, either.  It's meant to be a flag for `the_content()` to split the post content into multiple pages.  Without seeing exactly how your using your various custom fields, there's nothing anyone can recommend for you to do to split a post across multiple pages.  Pagination isn't a built-in feature for custom fields, so you're going to have to re-build the entire system to handle it.